# Jquery click outside multiple div/elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are two sections `targetDiv1` and `targetDiv2`(not nested). And another section `collapsibleDiv`. I need to run a function(be it collapsing the div) on clicking outside the element `targetDiv2`; but the function should not be triggerred when clicking `targetDiv1`. With the below code I'm unable to achieve this.. Any help would be great...

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    if(!$(e.target).closest('.targetDiv1').length && !$(e.target).is('.targetDiv1')) {
        $('.collapsibleDiv').slideDown();
    }
});
```

JSFiddle as per the answer from @Kweiss https://jsfiddle.net/vn8gmu8g/

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle for easier examination?

Comment: What is your function not achieving? It should work when you click anywhere other than targetDiv1

Comment: @KWeiss it should work on clicking outside targetDiv1 but should not work on clicking targetDiv2. document.click will trigger the function even if I click on targetDiv2

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want the function to execute on a click outside Div1 or Div2, but your code only excludes Div1. Just add Div2 as well.

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    var $target = $(e.target);
    if(!$target.closest('.targetDiv1').length && !$target.hasClass('targetDiv1') && 
       !$target.closest('.targetDiv2').length && !$target.hasClass('targetDiv2')) {
        $('.collapsibleDiv').slideDown();
    }
});
```

Saving `e.target` in a variable and using `hasClass()` will make your code faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $(".targetDiv2").click(function(){
           $('.collapsibleDiv').slideDown();
  })
```

It does what you want. It will collapse when you click `div2`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you have to add same if conditions for div2

```
$(document).click(function(e) {
    var $clickedElement = $(e.target); 
    if(!$clickedElement.closest('.targetDiv1').length && !$clickedElement.is('.targetDiv1') && !$clickedElement.closest('.targetDiv2').length && !$clickedElement.is('.targetDiv2')) {
        $('.collapsibleDiv').slideDown();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I created a [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/pg5t1oed/), and I would say, it is working...

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    if(!$(e.target).closest('.targetDiv1').length && !$(e.target).is('.targetDiv1')) {
        $('.collapsibleDiv').slideDown();
        alert("OK");
    }
});
```

> If you click on targetDiv1 -> nothing happens
>
> If you click on targetDiv2 -> alert
>
> If you click anywhere else -> alert

I would say, this is what you described.

Answer (score 0):

Below should work

`$(document).click(function(e) { 
    var target = $(e.target);
    if(!target.hasClass('.targetDiv1') && !target.hasClass('.targetDiv2')) {
        // perform you operation
    }
});`